# SSIS - OnError Send Email

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am designing an SSIS package that performs multiple tasks and sends an email with the result (Success or failure) of the package.

All the tasks in the package are connected by "Success" connectors (meaning that if ANY task fails the entire package fails) as shown in the screenshot of the control flow below.

My question is: would it be enough to configure the failure email just in the "OnError" piece (as shown in the other screenshot below) so that the users receive the error email only once when any task in the package is failed?

Thanks!

**Package Control Flow Screenshot**

[image]

**OnError Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: IF *`the error email will be sent only once when any task in the package is failed`* is your requirement then it is OK

Comment: Sending mail for each component, doesn&#39;t sounds good.
A good package design is, if you are sending mail for failure or any other events from event handler.